# nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2), it is not getting installed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, nodejs

I have a problem installing a newer version of `nodejs` on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I have tried the following command:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
```

Here is its error log: https://justpaste.it/7j74u

I then tried:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

And I got:

```
Reading package lists... 0%
Reading package lists... 100%
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... 0%
Building dependency tree... 0%
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree... 50%
Building dependency tree... 91%
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... 0%
Reading state information... 0%
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (4.2.6~dfsg-1ubuntu4.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 273 not upgraded.
```

Then, running `node -v` showed:

```
command not found
```

How can I install `node` on my Ubuntu?

Comment: Hey did you manage to solve this issue? I am getting the same problem

Comment: @GeneCode yes i'm able to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I followed

1. Install `nvm` (from [nvm GitHub page](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)):

   ```
   curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
   export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
   ```
2. Install latest `node` (Node.js for Linux):

   ```
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
   ```
3. Use that latest `nvm`:

   ```
   nvm use 14.0
   ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing it works now. I did try curl cmd before, but nothing happens at first time (ie no activity, it just go back to command prompt). I thought something was done. Turns out if there are errors, curl just not giving any output. So it must be said that after typing curl command, there should be some activity on the console. Anyway thanks again.

Comment: Nodesource is deprecated now.